# Lee's Method for measuring conductivity of a poor conductor

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, thermal-conduction

I have taken a lab course this semester and one of the experiments is the Lee's disc method to determine the conductivity of a poor conductor. For anyone unfamiliar with the experiment, [this is the experiment](http://sites.iiserpune.ac.in/%7Ebhasbapat/phy221_files/Lee%27s%20Method.pdf). In the second part of the experiment, where the lower disc is directly heated and then, after heating is cooled down with the poor conductor on top of it, our manual suggests that we heat the lower disc to $(T+10) \;\text{K}$ and allow it to cool down to $(T-7) \;\text{K}$ (where $T$ is the steady-state temperature). I have thought about this for a month and a half now but I have no clue why we take the cooling data asymmetrically around $T$. Any help on why this is the prescribed method would be much appreciated.